# (IE 11) Slick Next and Previous Arrows flicker which clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-11, slick.js

I am currently facing an issue with slick on IE11 where on pressing of next or previous buttons, the buttons flicker or go up/down. It's clearly visible even in the arrows shown in [Slick Demo](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) as well.

- IE Browser version : 11.0.9600

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sumodh

Comment: just a comment to confirm I got the same behaviour.  (Win 10 Preview, IE Version 11.1000.17667.0 Update Versions 11.0.47), not on Edge, FF or Chrome.

Comment: @johnc True. I couldn't replicate the same issue elsewhere. Only seem to happen with IE11.

Comment: Adding a background to the button shows it is not the button itself that is moving, but the pseudo element inside it - when the button is in the `:active` state. Wasn’t able to find out more on a quick glance (IE dev tools are rather sub-par), but that’s the direction I’d look into (what different styling might get applied to the button or the pseudo element in :active state, maybe from the browser stylesheet.)